# How to set a breakpoint in a Clojure program using Calva?

Tags: clojure, jvm, vscode-calva

I am working with a Clojure code and need to make changes in some parts of it. For that, I need to stop it in a breakpoint to see what are the values of atoms, variables, .... one step before new changes. The code I am working with is:
https://github.com/lspector/clojush
I need to stop it in [breed.clj](https://github.com/lspector/Clojush/blob/master/src/clojush/pushgp/breed.clj),defn perform-genetic-operator-list, at the end of line 99 (num-parents).
I am using Calva in VS code and run the code via the terminal with this command:
"lein run clojush.problems.demos.simple-regression".

I tried putting #break inside "num-parents (:parents (get genetic-operators operator))" as:

```
num-parents (:parents (get genetic-operators #break operator))
```

but it did not work and program stops showing some errors. Also I tried instrumentation and again did not work.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!